# RSpec: How do I refactor a group of tests that are repeated and the only thing that changes is the subject and expectations

Tags: refactoring, rspec

I have a test suite that resembles the situation I describe with the following code. There are two contexts that define the subject. The subject is similar, the same kind of object, but with different values.

Over that subject I run two tests. One test is exactly the same for both and the other is different.

Suggest a refactor that would eliminate duplication, besides the obvious 'move the code to a method', which I don't like because it looses clarity.

```
require 'rspec'

describe "tests over numbers" do
  context 'big numbers' do
    subject { 5000 }

    describe "#to_string" do
      its(:to_s) {should be_a(String)}
    end

    describe "#+1" do
      it "+1" do
        sum = subject+1
        sum.should == 5001
      end
    end        
  end
  context 'small numbers' do
    subject { 100 }

    describe "#to_string" do
      its(:to_s) {should be_a(String)}
    end

    describe "#+1" do
      it "+1" do
        sum = subject+1
        sum.should == 101
      end
    end        
  end                                           
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe shared examples is the way to go?

```
shared_example "numbers" do
  describe "#to_string" do
    it "should convert to a string" do
      example.to_s.should be_a(String)
    end
  end

  describe "#+1" do
    it "should increment" do
      sum = example+1
      sum.should == example.next
    end
  end
end

describe "big_numbers" do
  it_behaves_like "numbers" do
    let(:example) { 5000 }
  end
end

describe "small_numbers" do
  it_behaves_like "numbers" do
    let(:example) { 100 }
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I needed :)

Comment: Hey, no problem. I don't use shared examples as much as I should so it took me a minute to get it right. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
[5000, 100].each do |my_test|
    subject { my_test }

    describe "#to_string" do
      its(:to_s) {should be_a(String)}
    end

    describe "#+1" do
      it "+1" do
        sum = subject+1
        sum.should == my_test + 1
      end
    end        
end
```